# Amplitude of a Sinus, Simple question

Tags: trigonometry

I have a rather simple question.
I would like to find the Amplitude of a Sinus using mathematica:

```
w=10;    
5*Sin[w*t-2]
```

The Amplitude is obviously 5.

Now, what I tried was to first convert the Sinus into Exponential Form:

```
TrigToExp[5*Sin[w*t-2]]
```

And then to Take the Norm:

```
TrigToExp[5*Sin[w*t-2]] //Norm
```

but it does not work... Thanks, for any help!

Comment: It doesn't return what you expect because MMA doesn't know whether `t` and `w` are real or not. Wrap the whole lot in `ComplexExpand` and you'll get your answer: `5 Abs[Sin[2 - t w]]`

Comment: @Quantum_Oil How do want to implement it ? I tried it, but it does not work...

Comment: FindMaximum[5 Sin[x], x] (* Out[10]= {5., {x -> 1.5708}} *)

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Why not `Maximize[5 Sin[x], x]`?

Comment: @Michael E2 I just wanted something simpler than was presented before. But yes, why not? Maximize is even better because it gives a symbolic answer.

Answer (score 11):

One way is to use [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html).

```
range = 5*Sin[w*t - 2] /. t -> Interval[{-Infinity, Infinity}]
amplitude = Max[range]
(*
  Interval[{-5, 5}]
  5  
*)
```

Or, this would take into account a translation:

```
amplitude = (Max[range] - Min[range])/2
(* 5  *)
```

Comment: thanks a lot!... but why can I not simply convert it to a complex function and take the norm ? I don't see why it would not work ?

Comment: @DoHe Converting a function to an equivalent form does not change its value. What norm are you talking about? `Norm[5*Sin[w*t - 2]]` `TrigToExp[5*Sin[w*t-2]] //Norm` find the same thing, the absolute value of `5*Sin[w*t - 2]`, which changes with `t`, whether it's in terms of complex exponential functions or not.

Comment: @DoHe Maybe you're thinking of this sort of approach?: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fSn0g.png